# Can't send DOM var trough $_session

Tags: php, session, dom

I am extracting some parts from a html webpage using DOM+php and trying to send the results to other pages as $_SESSION variables and eventually to update a mysql DB.
example of the HTML webpage code:

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <div id="title">some title </div>
  <div id="city">some city</div> 
  <div id="country">some country</div> 
  <div id="company">some company</div>
  <div id="text">some text</div>
  <body>
  <html>
```

This is the code that I a using to get the data and is working...I can echo the $var:

```
<?php session_start(); ?> 
---- some HTML---
<?
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $file = 'webpage.html';
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($file);

    $title = $html->getElementById('title');
    $city = $html->getElementById('city');
    $country = $html->getElementById('country');
    $company = $html->getElementById('company');
    $text= $html->getElementById('text');

    echo '<b>'.$title.'</b>';
    $_SESSION['title'] =   $title;    
    echo '<b>'.$city.'</b>';
    $_SESSION['city'] =   $city;
    echo '<b>'.$country.'</b>';
    ..............
?>
```

My problem is that I can't send this $var ($title,$city, ...) to any other php page using $_SESSION... and I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string
```

Comment: PHP sessions can only contain *serializable* data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHP docs, sessions can only contain data that can be *serialized*.

> When PHP shuts down, it will automatically take the contents of the `$_SESSION` superglobal, serialize it, and send it for storage using the session save handler.

<sub>Source: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php</sub>

It looks like DOM elements unfortunately cannot be serialized and therefore cannot be stored in the session correctly.

**UPDATE**: It looks like you can fix this by casting the DOM elements as a string:

```
$_SESSION['title'] = (string)$title;
$_SESSION['city'] = (string)$city;
```

Comment: OK ...so there is any way to use this data that I am extracting with DOM ?

Comment: You can try to save it in the session as a string.  `$_SESSION['title'] =   (string)$title;`